# How to return the main query if join is empty?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an SQL query here:

**Given**:

1. `$id = 4;` (user's id)
2. `$date_now = date("Y-m-d");`

I'm using PHP

```
SELECT  `u`.name, 
        `u`.email, 
        `ud`.id, 
        `ud`.in, 
        `ud`.out 
FROM users u 
JOIN dtr ud ON `ud`.id = '$id' 
WHERE `ud`.entry_date = '$date_now' LIMIT 1
```

The query returns what I want when `dtr.id = $id where dtr.entry_date = $date_now` exist.

My problem is that, whenever user's dtr (user with `$id` is found in dtr table) does not exist, the query returns zero result. (Which is correct based on my query).

But what I want is to query `users.name` and `users.email` when *user's dtr does not exist*.

Comment: Use left join... LEFT JOIN dtr ud ON `ud`.id = '$id'.

Comment: still returns null

Comment: Try this : SELECT  `u`.name, 
        `u`.email, 
        `ud`.id, 
        `ud`.in, 
        `ud`.out 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN dtr ud ON `ud`.id = '$id' 
WHERE `ud`.entry_date LIKE %'$date_now'% LIMIT 1

Comment: still not working. i think the problem is in the where clause as ud.entry_date cannot be compared as it is null?

Comment: yes if it should null then not works. Should i write code if null then not to set.?

Comment: i got the answer. wait ill post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct query was using LEFT JOIN

with little modification:

```
SELECT  `u`.name, 
        `u`.email, 
        `ud`.id, 
        `ud`.in, 
        `ud`.out 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN dtr ud ON `ud`.id = '$id' AND `ud`.entry_date = '$date_now'
WHERE `u`.id = '$id' LIMIT 1
```

Where clause was not working because it's null in the first place.

Thanks to @Ruchish Parikh for collaborating

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless. And ud.id = u.id